# single query to get data for multiple dates

Tags: mysql

I want to fetch total number of stores added from 1 to 90 days. and i want to display them number of stores added in 7 days, 14 days, 30 days, 60 days and 90 days. I want to fetch all this by using 1 count query. 
I am using following query. If i use query in this way then i have to write query multiple times.

```
SEELCT COUNT(storeid) AS totalStores FROM example 
WHERE DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), date_created)
```

Comment: Just use a `UNION` to join the sql queries into one giant sql query. There is no way to optimize this query unless you look into creating summary tables or completely rehaul your database schema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it as a pivot:

```
SELECT
    sum(days <= 7) AS total7,
    sum(days <= 14) AS total14,
    sum(days <= 30) AS total30,
    sum(days <= 60) AS total60,
    sum(days <= 90) AS total90
FROM (
    SELECT DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), date_created) as days
    FROM example
) x
```

The `sum(condition)` syntax works (in mysql) because true is 1 and false is 0, so summing a condition neatly counts how many times its true.

The subquery is used to make the code more readable and to add a little performance (the call to `datediff()` is only made once per row).